# FB 'pages' have $pageID, what's a website equivalent?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, tracking, externalinterface

I'm trying to write a simple app for my website and struggling with 1 point.

A Facebook Page has;

```
$pageID = 'dorimedia';
```

What does a website have that is equal? I want to get the value to show how many times an external website has been 'liked'.

Comment: I'm trying to have a slider bar to show how many like an actual website has had. Here is my example, on my site (in the footer) www.dorimedia.co.nz

Comment: Can I somehow use a get_file_content command to pluck the details from here? https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.dori.co.nz/%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing.
You could use the domain name, or domain name + path as in full route, but no short ID per se.

- http://www.google.com could be the `id`
- http://www.google.com/route could also be an `id`

If you need something shorter, and not necessarily readable by you, you could hash it or apply some encrypting algorithm to the full url to get a shorter `id`, try looking into the `md5`,`sha1` or `hash` methods (assuming your using php)

**UPDATE**
If what you need is how many facebook like's a website has, there is an API for this directly from google that goes like this:

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=www.google.com
```

Which results in an xml response that includes, comments, likes and other interesting information. Google for instance has the following response:

```
<links_getStats_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd" list="true">
     <link_stat>
        <url>www.google.com</url>
        <normalized_url>http://www.google.com/</normalized_url>
        <share_count>2095550</share_count>
        <like_count>795778</like_count>
        <comment_count>705595</comment_count>
        <total_count>3596923</total_count>
        <click_count>265614</click_count>
        <comments_fbid>381702034999</comments_fbid>
        <commentsbox_count>307</commentsbox_count>
    </link_stat>
</links_getStats_response>
```

Then its a matter of extracting the information from that XML, easily enough like this:

```
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$shares =  $xml->link_stat->share_count;
$likes =  $xml->link_stat->like_count;
$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count;
$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;
$max = max($shares,$likes,$comments);
```

[Click here for the **Source**](http://allfacebook.com/calculate-facebook-like_b44023)

Comment: I tried the url in a bunch of different formats, didn't seem to work. I'm trying to have a slider bar to show how many like an actual website has had. Here is my example, on my site (in the footer) www.dorimedia.co.nz. Thanks